# Linq .All returning true for empty collection

Tags: c#, linq

Consider the following code:

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{
    List<string> items = new List<string>();
    string result = null;

    if(items.All(o => o == "ABC"))
    {
        result = "All";
    }
    else if(items.Any(o => o == "XYZ"))
    {
        result = "Any";
    }

    Console.WriteLine(result);
    Console.Read();
}
```

This prints "All".

Why does an **empty** list satisfy an "All" condition where `o == "ABC"`

Comment: Look at the source code [here](http://referencesource.microsoft.com/#System.Core/System/Linq/Enumerable.cs,be4bfd025bd2724c,references)

Comment: _Why_ is subjective, isn't it? Is the glass half-full or half-empty? `All` satisfy your condition because there are none. You can always check first if the list is empty.

Comment: I think you need to think about it in the opposite way. `.All(...)` is `true` so long as none exist that are `false`. If the list is empty then none exist that are `false` so it is `true`.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

According to MSDN:-

[Enumerable.All](https://msdn.microsoft.com/library/bb548541(v=vs.100).aspx)

> Return **true** if every element of the source sequence passes the
>   test in the specified predicate, or **if the sequence is empty**;
>   otherwise, false.

So in your case since `items` is an empty collection it is returning true.

Answer (score 5):

This is [by design](https://msdn.microsoft.com/library/bb548541(v=vs.110).aspx) and also consistent with how the [universal quantifier ∀](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Universal_quantification) works in mathematics on sets.